# Out of the $2N$ cards $N$ are chosen at random, and only these $N$ are matched against the target deck. Find the probability of no match.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> (Feller Volume 1, P.112, Q.20) There are two similar decks of $N$ distinct cards. Out of the $2N$ cards $N$ are chosen at random, and only these $N$ are matched against the target deck. Find the probability of no match.
>
> Answer: $\sum_{k=0}^N \frac{{N \choose k}2^k(2N-k)!(-1)^k}{(2N)!}$.

My attempt: We can arrange the target deck in a natural order: $1, 2, 3, ... , N$. We have ${2N \choose N}$ ways to choose $N$ cards. Let $A_k$ be the event that the card number $k$ is matched. Then, the probability of no match is $1- P(A_1 \cup A_2 \cup \cdot\cdot\cdot \cup A_N)$. Then, I can use the inclusion and exclusion method.

But, I am not sure how to compute $P(A_i), P(A_i \cap A_j),...$, and I don't know if this is the right approach. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$P\left(A_{1}\cap\cdots\cap A_{k}\right)=P\left(A_{1}\right)P\left(A_{2}\mid A_{1}\right)\cdots P\left(A_{k}\mid A_{1}\cap\cdots\cap A_{k-1}\right)=$$$$\frac{1}{2N-1}\frac{1}{2N-3}\cdots\frac{1}{2N-2k+1}=\frac{2^{k}N!\left(2N-2k\right)!}{\left(2N\right)!\left(N-k\right)!}$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. May I ask how did you get $P(A_1)$?

Comment: Because the $N$ cards are taken *at random* the process comes to the same as picking two cards repeatedly out of all the $2N$ cards (without replacement) where there is a match if both cards are the same. If I have picked my first card then $2N-1$ cards are left and among them there is exactly one that matches the first.